# Dates don't compare correctly in Titanium Mobile

Tags: javascript, datetime, titanium, titanium-mobile

Take the following code:

```
var first = new Date("2011-09-17T15:12:04.331Z");
var second = new Date("2011-09-17T19:55:19.269Z");
alert(first < second);
```

In a browser (http://jsfiddle.net/fdqjs/0/), it alerts true. In Titanium Mobile, it alerts 0, or false. Why is this? I cannot get the dates in a different format from the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that Titanium Mobile isn't running a new enough version of Javascript to cover the date format you're using.

If you look up the specification for the Date object, it takes a date as defined in [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123) which gets it's date defintion from [RFC 822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-3) which does not look to me like it supports the exact format you're using.  Starting in Javascript 1.8.5, it also accepts dates in the form of [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) which looks like it might cover what you have.

I'd suggest modifying your date strings to work like the older specification if you can.  See [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for more info.

An example of a valid RFC822 date time is this:

```
02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200
```

If your dates are always in exactly the format you show in your question, then you can do a simple conversion like this:

```
function ConvertDate(dateIn) {
    var monthStr = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
    // desired format "02 Oct 2002 15:00:00 +0200"
    var dateOut = dateIn;
    var matches = dateIn.match(/(\d+)\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)T(.*)Z$/);
    if (matches) {
        dateOut = matches[3] + " " + 
            monthStr[parseInt(matches[2] - 1, 10)] + " " + 
            matches[1] + " " + 
            matches[4] + " GMT";
    }
    return(dateOut);
}
```

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/APxN7/.

Note: this simple function assumes your dates are always in the exact format you show in your question and always valid as it will not handle any arbitrary ISO 8601 date as input, only exactly the form you show.

To get the current date into a javascript object, you can just do this:

```
var now = Date();
```

You can then use any of the [methods defined for the Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) on the `now` object, include methods to get any part of the date or convert it to a string, etc....

To get the internet form of the date that ConvertDate outputs, you would use:

```
now.toUTCString();
```

Comment: How would I modify the date strings to work like the older specification? Can i do that in javascript before I parse them? I'm getting the dates from an external source that I have no control over.

Comment: I'm going the same direction as you - just added a simple conversion routine to my answer - was working on it before you asked.

Comment: Seems to work, as long as i don't put the ConvertDate output into new Date(output)

Comment: I fixed a problem in the code (month was off by one).  Make sure you get the current version.

Comment: Ah, didn't even notice that! Thanks for fixing.

Comment: Sorry to bother you more, but how would I get the current time into the above format that ConvertDate outputs?

Comment: I added a bit about the current date to the end of my answer.  You should read the MDN doc on the Date object: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks for the link and all the help!

Comment: Sorry about that.  There are lots of other string functions in the Date object.  I don't know exactly what you need the string format for, but perhaps `.toUTCString()` would work.

Comment: No, it was my bad. I called .toISOString() without the parentheses. :-)